# Make a Linux shell with launch arguments?

Tags: shell

Is there a way I can make a shell script start with launch arguments? I need this for a project I'm working on. It would be great if you can give me example code like this.

1. User types `sh helloworld.sh -hi`
2. The shell than echos `hi` (or whatever comes after the `-`)

Comment: The command line arguments are in `$@`.

Answer (score 0):

for just the first argument:

```
echo $1 | sed -e 's/^-//g'
```

For all of them minus the "-"

```
for i in $@
do
    echo $i | sed -e 's/^-//g'
done
```

remove the `| sed -e 's/^-//g'` part if you don't care about the leading `-`.

Comment: You could also write: `echo "${i#-}"` to strip the leading dash.

Comment: I found out how to do what I was looking for. You can just do echo $*